# gulp-inject with gulp-jade

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

Its my first day with gulp - Im trying to use gulp-inject to put some script files and jade files converted to html that exist in an app folder into a 'temp' folder which is using webserver to serve up the html.  I can make this work all right if I'm just using static html but when I switch to jade it only works AFTER the first time I run gulp (Im guessing because it is still processing the gulp-jade 'jade()' the first time through so there is not html to inject into -  and so I have this code (granted I'm half way through a tutorial so this may not even be the proper way to use gulp but the tutorial is not using jade which I prefer)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var server = require('gulp-webserver');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

var paths = {
  app: 'app/**/*.js',
  bower: 'bower_components',
  jade: 'app/*.jade',
  temp: 'temp',
  tempVendor: 'temp/vendor',
  index: 'temp/index.html'
}

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);


gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  gulp.src(paths.jade)
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));

var appFiles = gulp.src(paths.app).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));
var vendor = gulp.src(mainBower()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tempVendor));

gulp.src(paths.index)
  .pipe(inject(appFiles,{relative:true}))
  .pipe(inject(vendor, {relative:true, name: 'vendorinject'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your gulp task into 2 tasks and use gulp dependencies to ensure 1 runs and finishes before the other starts.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var server = require('gulp-webserver');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

var paths = {
  app: 'app/**/*.js',
  bower: 'bower_components',
  jade: 'app/*.jade',
  temp: 'temp',
  tempVendor: 'temp/vendor',
  index: 'temp/index.html'
}

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);

gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.jade)
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['jade'], function(){ 
    var appFiles = gulp.src(paths.app).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));
    var vendor = gulp.src(mainBower()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tempVendor));

    gulp.src(paths.index)
      .pipe(inject(scripts,{relative:true}))
      .pipe(inject(vendor, {relative:true, name: 'vendorinject'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.temp));
});
```

This way your scripts task will only run and inject once the jade task has finished.